# Pronounced 麼 as mo?

Tags: characters, pronunciation, taiwan

In Taiwan, how common is it to pronounce 麼 as 'mo', in words like 什麼, 怎麼, 那麼, etc...

I know 麼 means small or tiny when pronounced as 'mó' in Standard Mandarin, and when in the words above, it's pronounced as 'me'.  However, I've heard quite a few people pronounce it as 'mó' in words where one I thought it would be pronounced as 'me'.

SO, how common is 什麼, 怎麼, etc... pronounced as shénmo or zěnmo in Taiwan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is so pronounced predominately by Taiwanese whose families came from Fujian province. I think it is part of the local dialect.